# Why won't my Rails 4.2.0 tests run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have no idea why this isn't working. I've generated a model test in a Rails 4.2.0 app using "rails g test_unit:model", and "rake test" does nothing.

```
$ rake test
```

Here's the dir structure of test/ (I also have no idea why `test_helper.rb` wasn't generated, nor do I know how to generate it.)

```
$ find test
test
test/models
test/models/domain_test.rb
```

The contents of my test:

```
$ more test/models/domain_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class DomainTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "URL gets transformed into domain" do
    domain = Domain.create("http://google.com/")
    expected = "google.com"
    assert expected, domain.name, "domain name could not be extracted from URL"
  end

end
```

My Rakefile:

```
$ more Rakefile
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... new Rails 4.2.0 apps have `# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"`
 commented out of `config/application.rb`. I un-commented it and copied a `test_helper.rb` from an old project and the tests now run.